# Image shows in the background after rotating

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap, rotation

I wrote a function that rotated an image, to make it fast (which is really important for rotating hundreds of photos) I didn't make a new bitmap every time I rotate the image. But, this resulted the old photo to appear in the background, how could I fix that without creating a new bitmap which will slow down everything!

```
    public static Image RotateImage(Image img, float rotationAngle)
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            graphics.TranslateTransform((float)img.Width / 2, (float)img.Height / 2);
            graphics.RotateTransform(rotationAngle);
            graphics.TranslateTransform(-(float)img.Width / 2, -(float)img.Height / 2);
            graphics.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));
        }
        return img;
    }
```

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible without extra code.

`Graphics` is **associated** with the image, so drawing will change the image.

So, you will need to have a 2nd image. **Creating** an empty one (or an exact copy) is not so slow..

Think of of it this way: Where could the old pixels come from when you are at the same time changing them?  So you need to have two buffers. (But yes, internally, there is already a 2nd buffer or else the results would be even a lot weirder. But you can't control the use of it..)

If you really feel the need to avoid a 2nd image you can create a `GraphicsPath` or a `Polygon` that covers **all but** the rotated image and fill it with your background color..

But since rotating an image will need **more space** to accomodate the rotated corners you probably need a 2nd, **larger** image anyway..

**Update:** Here is an example of how to clear/crop the area outside the rotated imgae. It uses a `GraphicsPath` to which I first add a huge and then the target rectangle. This way a **hole** is cut and only the **outside** area is filled:

```
public static Image RotateImage(Image img, float rotationAngle)
{
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img))
    {
        graphics.TranslateTransform((float)img.Width / 2, (float)img.Height / 2);
        graphics.RotateTransform(rotationAngle);
        graphics.TranslateTransform(-(float)img.Width / 2, -(float)img.Height / 2);
        graphics.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));

        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
        GraphicsUnit gu = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        gp.AddRectangle(graphics.ClipBounds);
        gp.AddRectangle(img.GetBounds(ref gu));
        graphics.FillPath(Brushes.White, gp);
    }
    return img;
}
```

Note that you can't use a **transparent** brush as GDI+ will not paint full transparency. Instead you would need to

1. Set the `CompositingMode`from its default `SourceOver` to `SourceCopy`;
2. Fill with a very distinct color, not in your image, maybe `Fuchsia`
3. Use `MakeTransparent`.

---

```
graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
..
graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Fuchsia, gp);
((Bitmap)img).MakeTransparent(Color.Fuchsia);
```

Note that not all applications will show transparency well.. Photoshop, of course, does..:

[image]

Comment: just wondering, is this more efficient and faster than creating a new bitmap?

Comment: It's way faster than creating a new bitmap, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

you could use the [Graphics Clear()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.clear?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Graphics_Clear_System_Drawing_Color_) method

Comment: it covered everything, I only need to cover the background